# How to find the sketch energy of the capacitor (let's say versus time) with the q-v plot shown below?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, capacitance

I wonder what is the plot of the energy of the so-called capacitor,it's will be 0 except in 2 and 3 that is a delta function but when we want to calculate it's energy we don't know the exact value of voltage in the time 2 ,3.Is it correct to simply integrate the q-v plot from V=2 to V=0?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUUcW.png) [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The energy stored on a capacitor is CV^2/2 or 1/2 Q V.

In the problem given above it is simply the area under the Q-V curve. So you will get two different (nonzero) values for your energy depending on the time.

Comment: As it is shown in the q-v plot  it is not a linear capacitor.so we must integrate.

Comment: The plot shows a voltage over time.

Comment: click on the link above it ,it will appear.I want the energy of the capacitor with that characteristic plot and that voltage over time.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand. I' ll update the answer accordingly.